# How to assign different border styles in Sketch?

Tags: borders, sketch-app

I needed to assign different border styles for a shape, let's say rectangle. For example, I want to make a #666 1px top border and #333 2px bottom border like we do in CSS.

```
{
  border-top: 1px solid #666;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #333;
}
```

Anyone knows a practical way to do this? 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, not possible with Sketch at this time. You could duplicate the shape and apply 2 different borders and overlay them on top of each other to get the desired effect.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @huptur. I'm pretty much sure that I saw someone doing it but I can't find the tutorial.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can fake the different border styles with shadows.

For the example you posted, you can add two shadows with the following settings:

[image]

Here's what you will get in Sketch:

[image]

Comment: A great video about your approach can be watched here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rkDUtJsJVTE

Comment: In reply to @Thanos. You need to use inner shadow. Not just shadow.